# Hiding files without affecting the software or operating system's functionality

Tags: linux, dot-files

Random software keeps on creating folders in my home folder which gets messed up and disorganized. I decided to clean things up. I added a dot `.` in the beginning of the folder's names in order to hide them, but quickly realized that dot affects folder names and folders weren't found by the software anymore. I ended up with a broken software...

So it looks like for the moment in Unix & Linux it is either **disorganized folder structure** or **disfunctional software**.

This is bugging me and I am asking if there is alternate way of hiding folders and files without affecting functionality?

---

Biased part of the question:

> In my opinion it is unwise to look at the OS just from perspective of functionality but also beauty. `chmod` and `chown` are there to take care of the functional part  (**file and folder protection**), so using `.` becomes redundant except from perspective of beauty (**hiding files**). Instead `.` also affects the name and interferes with functionality. Therefore my opinion is that we need a different mechanism to hide files without affecting the functionality.

Comment: Forget about hiding. Play with permissions

Comment: `git` or any other VCS supports ignore lists.

Comment: While this question is valid I think you should ask yourself whether you really need this. I would argue that there are not many use cases for hiding.

Comment: I beg your pardon, but what are you actually asking? Not displaying Files beginning with a dot is pure convention. The kernel itself does not care, from its perspective there is no such concept as hidden files, i.e. there is no file attribute for this. So we are left with: _In my opinion Linux developers could present us with a better mechanism_ ... what for? Use case where that really matters? Improvement worth the effort?

Comment: Renaming a configuration file is likely to break an application regardless of whether or not it begins with a dot. Consider `/etc/hosts`. No dot there but renaming it will cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: @countermode You only look at this from the perspective of functionality. But what about beauty? Or organisation from a regular user's point of view? It happens to me that random software just keeps creating folders in my home folder and totally ruins my organisation. So if I add a dot to those folders to hide them, I end up with non-working software. **This is not a problem?**

Comment: @71GA How else should I look at it. Have you ever used IT in a production environment? Nobody cares about beauty. _random software just keeps creating folders in my home folder and totally ruins my organisation_ - eh, what?! Are you watching the `ls -l` output and admiring its beauty?!

Comment: @countermode I am 100% Linux user for 10 years now and my bachelors was ARM programming in Linux. I have been doing the later for 6 years now. Well this `.` thingie is something that annoys me from the beginning... Why? Because I don't use Linux only from perspective of functionality but also it's beauty and customizability as a desktop environment.  We all know  is so successful because it pays great deal of focus to beauty. So it isn't wise to neglect beauty part of operating system if we want Linux to thrive. Wayland is well on the way and with it Linux may expand in desktop field.

Answer (score 3):

The real solution to put a file out of the way is to put it in a different directory.

Files whose name begin with a dot are hidden by default in some software, out of ancient Unix tradition. It started with the `ls` command and has been imitated by many, but not all, file managers.

There is a proposal to hide files whose name is listed in a file called `.hidden`, which [originated in Gnome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#GNOME). It doesn't have very widespread support. You could try using it but don't expect all the software that your users use to hide them. If users see the files in some software but not in other, this may well be counterproductive — they might delete the files that they see in program A but not in program B, thinking that if program B doesn't show the files then there's something wrong with them and they probably shouldn't be there. For this reason, although I inform you that this feature exists but I recommend against using it.

Once again, if you don't want users to mess up with some files, put them in a different directory. And, if applicable, don't give them permission to mess with those files.

Comment: `hidden` is the wrong term to use IMHO. `Not displayed by default` is the term I use.  There is nothing hidden about dorfiles. They are simply not displayed by `ls`  and GUI file managers without an extra option.

Comment: I rewrote my question. Gnome seems to be heading in the right direction...

Comment: Voted to reopen.  But IMHO you're looking for something that won't be implemented in the near future.

Comment: I agree. But maybe someday it will be.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 “Hidden” doesn't mean “invisible”. It means “not currently visible” or “not visible without effort”. So “hidden” is perfectly fine for a file that is not shown by default in directory listings, but can be shown by toggling a setting.

Comment: @Giles.  I never used the term `invisible`.  I used the phrase `not displayed by default` which is very similar to the phrase used by you in your reply, i.e. `not shown by default`

Comment: @Giles There is no difference between terms you used nor does it make any sense to point this out. Hidden is a **synonym** for:  concealed, secret, not visible, invisible, unseen, not on view, out of sight, covered, camouflaged, disguised, masked, shrouded, veiled, unrevealed... Link: https://www.google.si/search?q=hidden+meanning&oq=hidden+meanning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5287j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Files beginning with a dot (*dotfiles*) are meant to be used by an application,
 and usually they specify the application's configuration; they aren't meant to be operated by the end user, which doesn't even need to be aware of them.

So the purpose of dotfiles isn't really to "clean our mess" and ever less to "prevent new users to mess things up" (that's what permissions are for; note that dotfiles can easily be seen via `ls -a`), but simply to organize files and reduce clutter by separating system-related files (dotfiles) from user-created data.

The reason why there isn't another system in place to hide files is because it was considered redundant, dotfiles having already proven their purpose. Note that in Linux, unlike MS Windows, there is no "hidden" attribute for files, although there are many others (type `man chattr` to see them).

If you want to prevent users from accessing files, and not simply hide files from them, there are other mechanisms: permissions (chmod), ACLs, up to SELinux access control.

Comment: Imagine the case when application puts a folder in my home folder and I don't like that, because it is ugly. So if this folder is needed by a program I am unable to move it nor can I hide it to keep my organizaton of files clean (because dot changes the name). What I am stating is that Linux could at least provide a mechanism to hide it without affecting the name...  I still don't understand why my question is being marked as a opinion based. It is not. **I am exposing a problem afterall**...

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Openbox desktop keeps it's files in `~/.config/openbox` and these files are supposed to be manipulated by the end user in order to customize his desktop. This is also sugested in `man openbox` so `.` files clearly aren't to be manipulated only by software.

Comment: @71GA.   You are exposing a perceived problem for you - not an actual problem for the majority of users of Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: @71GA The meaning of a dotfile it's "this is a system configuration file and not user-created data, you can modify it if you like and you know what you're doing, otherwise keep your hands off"

Comment: @dr01 So if `.` was meant to mark system configuration files (which I believe you) this means that along the way people started **exploiting** it to hide files - but this is the task `.` fails to do without complications as can be seen from my example... Hence we should point out true meaning of `.` and create new mechanism for hiding files.