# Is there a way to hide a folder without changing its name?

Tags: cinnamon, nemo

I have a few apps that create visible folders in my home directory by default. I would like to hide these folders so I don't have to see them when I open Nemo. I prefer to see only the folders I actually use, such as Documents, Videos, Music, Projects, etc. Making them dotfiles either makes the app freak out because it can't find the folder any longer, or, in one case, the app just creates the folder again the next time it is run. Is there a way to hide these files? Perhaps a way to create some sort of alias so the app could search for a given directory, but be redirected to a dotfile? I'm using Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon.

Note: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366489/hiding-files-without-affecting-the-software-or-operating-systems-functionality/366666#366666), as that ended up being a debate on the usefulness of file hiding in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nemo uses GLib, so you should have access to the `.hidden` feature that it provides.

Create a file named `.hidden` in the parent directory containing the files or directories that you want to hide, then in this `.hidden` file list everything you want to hide, e.g.

```
Documents
Videos
Music
```

All files listed in `.hidden` will be hidden by default (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide).

([feature's source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/commit/510ba9b4efe1813e24c6dfa7405c3547bf9efdd7))

Comment: Just tested... Works in Caja as well.